# Wordpress Elementor, SourceMap Could not load content of pickr js file

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm working with elementor 2.9.13, i got this `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for website/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/pickr/pickr.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE` on my Chrome Browser, is there any way to fix this, thanks

Comment: Which version of Elementor do you using?

Comment: I'm working with elementor 2.9.13

Comment: Update to 2.9.14 maybe helps.

Comment: OK  thanks for suggestion